# How can I increase the max windows for the stock browser?

Tags: settings, browser, ram

I use the stock browser, and I find it's the best for my purposes.  One thing is annoying, however -- I can't have more than four windows open. Is there a way to increase this?  I have a Galaxy S Vibrant running 2.2 (Nero v5 with TouchWiz), and plenty of memory for more windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From looking at some posts on Android Forums [(1)](http://androidforums.com/htc-desire/58138-desire-browser-only-4-windows.html), [(2)](http://androidforums.com/desire-support-troubleshooting/280639-increasing-number-tabs-stock-browser.html) I think it's just not possible - to get more windows/tabs you'll need to use another browser like Dolphin HD/Mini.

**Edit:** Looks from [this post on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=793782) that it's hard-coded into the browser; it can be changed, but not easily.

Comment: I myself moved to Dolphin Mini as it has unlimited Tabs, loads from cold as quick as the stock browser with way more functionality.

Comment: I agree - I moved to Dolphin Mini a while ago and haven't looked back.

Comment: I'm a power user and developer, so I have no problem hacking the browser to do it.  Presumably I can't use the version in that thread since it's for the Desire, but it provides a good starting point.  Thanks.